# How to filter text in SearchView and CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I am trying to filter the text when i type some text in the searchview, but it doesn't display any thing. I check the cursor and it contains data after the retrieval of local data. Is there something wrong with my CursorAdapter? Can someone help me with it? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 //retrieve data from local database and pass into ArrayList result
                 DatabaseManager databaseManager1 = DatabaseManager.instance();
                    ArrayList<Locations> result = databaseManager1.searchLocationsByName(text);                
                    MatrixCursor cursor= new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
                    for(Locations l : result){          
                            String [] info = {"",l.getBuildingname(),String.valueOf(l.getLat()),String.valueOf(l.getLong())};
                            cursor.addRow(info);                          
                    }                     

                    searchViewAdapter= new SearchViewAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),cursor);
```

If i replace the above line with

```
                searchViewAdapter.changeCursor(cursor),
```

the app will crash. What is wrong?

```
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Here is my SearchViewAdapter:

```
        public class SearchViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
            private ContentResolver resolver;
            private Cursor cursor;
            public SearchViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
                super(context,cursor,0);
                resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                this.cursor = cursor;
            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent,false);
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                TextView textView = (TextView)view;
                final int textIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Name");
                textView.setText(cursor.getString(textIndex));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: does databaseManager1 retrieve data from sqlite db?

Comment: how stupid i am. I fixed it. I did not check the log. The error came from the String info where id = "". ty

Comment: does databaseManager1 use sqlite db ?

Comment: yes. it connects to sqlite. everything works fine now

Comment: great, but why if you have sqlite db, you dont return a Cursor from 
searchLocationsByName(text) but instead you return a list and then based on that list you create a MatrixCursor?